# Load specific test via TestLoader

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm using python unit test, and want to load (and run) a specific test by specifying its path.

I'm looking for something like this:
    `unitTest.TestLoader().Load('path_to_test')`

(This is needed for further parsing)

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I endded up having a simple parser to convert `/` to `.` (in the path) to load the specific test. Something like this:

```
        splitted_path = path.split("/")

        test_dir = '/'.join(splitted_path[:-1])
        test_name = splitted_path[-1]
        if not test_name.startswith('test'):
            raise RuntimeError(
                'Test name ({}) does NOT start with "test"'.format(
                    test_name))
        tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover(
            test_dir, pattern=test_name)
```